# Set CPU limit in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I got a on-prem server which I would like to deploy many micro-services. I'm using a docker-compose file to declare all services and would like to set the cpu limit. I refer the docs below: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
My docker compose file is like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 256M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 64M
  service1:
    image: service1 image
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 64M

...
```

I'm confused to calculate the cpus limits. For example, the cpu is 8 cores. There are 20 microservices. 
Is there any way I can calculate the cpu limit of each service? Or any formulas to do so?

----- UPDATE ------
To make it clearer, my main point here is CPU limit. It is because I'd like to send alert if the CPU of one microservice is using 80% of CPU for that microservice. If I don't set the cpu limit, is it true that the microservice CPU usage will be the same with host CPU usage? I don't use Docker's Swarn but Docker only.

Any ideas are really appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 16):

Welcome to 2022.  I'm using version 1.29 of docker-compose with a yaml version of 3.9

If I set my yml file as follows:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

    astro-cron:
        build: ./cron
        image: astro-cron
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
          - /home/docker-sync/sites/com/cron:/astro/cron
        environment:
          - TZ=America/Phoenix
        mem_limit: 300m
        mem_reservation: 100m
        cpus: 0.3
```

It nicely limits the container cpu to 30% of the machine.
The memory limits kill the container if exceeded, which will
auto-restart.

The cpu limit does not kill anything, just holds.

I'm not using docker swarm.

PS.  To address the other answer of having an overcommitted cpu not being a problem.  It IS a problem if one of your containers is an unimportant background job, and another is a customer facing web site or database.  Unless someone can explain why that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Finally can use my host's web browser while my nodejs container compiles up a storm thanks to this :)

Comment: In most cases I would avoid having background jobs, databases and webservers running with docker compose in production, if possible. The cpu limit is also absolute, not relative. In the example the CPU usage on the host for astro-cron would be limited to 30%, no matter how many cores docker is assigned.

Answer (score 4):

Having overcommitted CPU isn't really a problem.  If you have 16 processes and they're all trying to do work requiring 100% CPU on an 8-core system, the kernel will time-share across the processes; in practice you should expect those processes to get 50% CPU each and the task to just take twice as long.  One piece of advice I've heard (in a Kubernetes space) is to set CPU requests based on the steady-state load requirement of the service, and to not set CPU limits.

There's no magic formula to set either of these numbers.  The best way is to set up some metrics system like Prometheus, run your combined system, and look at the actual resource utilization.  In some cases it's possible to know that a process is single-threaded and will never use more than 1 core, or that you expect a process to be I/O bound and if it's not it should get throttled, but basing these settings on actual usage is probably better.

(Memory is different, in that you can actually run out of physical memory, but also that processes are capable of holding on to much more memory than they actually need.  Again a metrics tool will be helpful here.)

Your question suggests a single host.  The [`deploy:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy) section only works with Docker's Swarm cluster manager.  If you're not using Swarm then you need to use a `version: '2'` `docker-compose.yml` file, which has [a different set of resource constraint declarations](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) (and mostly doesn't have the concept of "reservations").  For example,

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    # cpus: 2.0
    mem_limit: 256m
    mem_reservation: 64m
```

Comment: +1 for @David Maze at least for the answer. Yes, in my case, the requirement is  just to use Docker in an on-prem server. There is not Docker's Swarm. My main point here is CPU limit. It is because I'd like to send alert if the CPU of one microservice is using 80% of CPU for that microservice. If I don't set the cpu limit, is it true that the microservice CPU usage will be the same with host CPU usage?

Comment: As of 2023, this advice is deprecated, compose version 3.4 gives you local access to the `deploy` section, including `deploy.resources.limits.cpus` and `...limits.memory`. Additionally in recent compose, you can't write plain `2` anymore, you need  say `2000m` , for 2000 milli-CPUs.

Comment: The documentation for the stable (Docker calls it "legacy") Compose v3 file format still contains a [note](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy) that `deploy:` is only honored in swarm mode.